# How to get the absolute difference between two angles

Tags: trigonometry

I need a function that will give me the shortest separation between angles that range from -pi to pi.  For example if I have two angles 3pi/4 and -3pi/4, I would like a function that will tell me pi/2 instead of 3pi/2.

Comment: `angleDifference[a_, b_] := With[{d = Mod[a - b, 2 π]}, If[d > π, d - 2 π, d]]`

Comment: Thank you. This answers the question.

Comment: @RahulNarain Or `angleDifference[a_, b_] := -Mod[b - a, 2 Pi, -Pi]`

Comment: The title says absolute difference, but the question specifies the range to be `-π` το `π`, which suggests negative answers are possible.  Do you want the (signed) difference or the absolute value of the difference?

Comment: For the absolute difference: `Abs @ Mod[a - b, 2 Pi, -Pi]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eldo's answer only works for a very restricted set of inputs. Here is a much more general solution.

```
validNum = Except[_Complex, _?NumericQ];

eldoDiff[θ1 : validNum, θ2 : validNum] := 
  Plus @@ ({θ1, θ2} /. Rational[a_, b_] :> Rational[1, b])

mgDiff[θ1 : validNum, θ2 : validNum] :=
 (With[{a = Mod[Abs[θ1 - θ2], 2 π]}, Min[a, 2 π - a]] /. Degree -> π/180)

data = {{-((3 π)/4), (3 π)/4}, {-135 °, 135 °}, {-2, 1}};
TableForm[
  MapThread[eldoDiff[##], mgDiff[##] &, Transpose[data]],
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"eldo", "mg"}}]
```

[image: table]

`eldoDiff` gives the correct result only for the first pair of arguments, while `mgDiff` gives the correct result for all three pairs.

Comment: +1, BUT ! to account for all cases somebody should edit the question ("shortest separation between angles that range from -pi to pi").

Comment: @edo. You're right in thinking the question could have been posed better. However, I think it is best to try read between the lines and come up with an answer that will be useful in the broadest possible circumstances. Going beyond the strict requirements of the original question is usually a good idea. Remember, as well as trying to help the OP, we should also support the SE goal of building an archival body of useful _Mathematica_ practice in QA form.

Answer (score 3):

```
VectorAngle[{Cos[#1], Sin[#1]}, {Cos[#2], Sin[#2]}] & @@ {3 Pi/4, -3 Pi/4}
```

**Edit.**

taking the point mentioned by m_goldberg:

```
data = {{-((3 π)/4), (3 π)/4}, {-135 °, 135 °}, {-2, 1}};

VectorAngle[{Cos[#1], Sin[#1]}, {Cos[#2], Sin[#2]}] & @@@ data//Simplify

(*  {Pi/2, Pi/2, 3}  *)
```

Comment: `Arg[Exp[I (Subtract @@ #)]] & /@ {{-3 π/4, 3 π/4}, {-135 °, 135 °}, {-2, 1}} // FullSimplify` is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
angleDifference[a_, b_] := ArcCos[Cos[a-b]]
```